# Fantasy: people take on traits of rabbits, eagles, snakes,

Tags: story-identification, books

Main character is a teen girl whose family has powers. They take on the traits of a certain animal. Her sister took on the traits of a rabbit. At the end of the book the main character takes on the traits of an eagle. One of the antagonists in the book took on the traits of a snake. Main character was a rich girl. She’s sent to some type of camp to find out what her animal is. People who were eagles could fly. People who were rabbits could jump very high and were agile.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read this?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) that might help you remember more details to [edit] into your question.